# Cypher: how to navigate graph to find the right path

Tags: graph, neo4j, navigation, relationship

I'm new to Cypher, I'm trying to learn to navigate a graph correctly.
I hava a situation like this: 2 Users have associated the same Service, the service is accessible via an Account. So, the user 'usr01' can access to the Service 'srv01' with account 'acct01'; the user 'usr02 can access to the Service 'srv01' with account 'acct02'.
The aim is to extract 2 records like this:

```
usr01 - srv01 - acct01
usr02 - srv01 - acct02
```

So, I executed these queries:

- Creation of nodes:

  ```
  create (s:XService {serviceId:'srv01'}) return s;

  create (u:XUser {userId:'usr01'}) return u;

  create (u:XUser {userId:'usr02'}) return u;

  create (u:XAccount {accountId:'acct01'}) return u;

  create (u:XAccount {accountId:'acct02'}) return u;
  ```
- Relationship creation:

  ```
  MATCH (u:XUser{userId:'usr01'}), (s:XService {serviceId:'srv01'}), (a:XAccount {accountId:'acct01'})
  CREATE (u)-[:HAS_SERVICE]->(s)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(a)

  MATCH (u:XUser{userId:'usr02'}), (s:XService {serviceId:'srv01'}), (a:XAccount {accountId:'acct02'}) 
  CREATE (u)-[:HAS_SERVICE]->(s)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(a)
  ```

The graph result I've received is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4ljI.jpg)

If I execute this query - starting from the user usr01:

```
MATCH (u:XUser {userId: 'usr01'}) OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:HAS_SERVICE]->(s:XService) OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(a:XAccount)
```

RETURN u.userId, s.serviceId, a.accountId;

I obtain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heR7Y.jpg) result:

So, how can I do to obtain the result described above (usr01 - srv01 - acct01) and not the cartesian product that I've received? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you add the relationship between the service and the account you do not indicate an association relationship with the user. As a solution, you can make a smart node "Access Rule":

```
MERGE (s:XService {serviceId:'srv01'})

MERGE (u1:XUser {userId:'usr01'})
MERGE (ua1:XAccount {accountId:'acct01'})
MERGE (u1)-[:can_access]->(ca1:AccessRule)-[:to_service]->(s)
MERGE (ca1)-[:with_account]->(ua1)

MERGE (u2:XUser {userId:'usr02'})
MERGE (ua2:XAccount {accountId:'acct02'})
MERGE (u2)-[:can_access]->(ca2:AccessRule)-[:to_service]->(s)
MERGE (ca2)-[:with_account]->(ua2)
```

And a query:

```
MATCH (u:XUser {userId: 'usr01'})
OPTIONAL MATCH ps = (u)-[:can_access]->(ca1:AccessRule)-[:to_service]->(s:XService)
OPTIONAL MATCH pa = (ca1)-[:with_account]->(a:XAccount)
RETURN u, ps, pa
```

Comment: It seems to be working correctly! Thank you very much!